# What is the test statistic in this example?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, bootstrap

I have a sample from a country's population. I am trying to figure out what is the test statistic for a certain question. The data contains 1400 people.. with ages, consumes alcohol or not, and wages.

The question is: **among people who are 40 years old or more, does drinking increase the wage?**

**The hypotheses are:**

H0: Among people who are 40 years old or older, drinking rises the wage.

H1: Among people who are 40 years old or older, drinking does not rise the wage.

So of course trying to decide this for the whole population, based on this 1400 sample. I know that a test statistic should be quantified but I just don't know how in this particular case.

**My shot at this:**

The test statistic is that drinkers above 40 have higher wages than nondrinkers, and to get that I calculated the average wages for drinkers vs non-drinkers in that group of age.

So yeah for drinkers and non-drinkers I calculated the mean of wages, but now what? if my attempt is correct, how do I quantify it, what would the test statistic be mathematically?

Thanks !!

Comment: You are right just to look at the data for those over $40$. There are two other issues. First, with a random sample, the sample average incomes of those who drink and those who do not are likely to to be different even if in the population they are not, and you may want to consider whether the difference you observe in the samples is so extreme that it would be unlikely to occur if there is no difference in the population.  Second, you do not know the direction of causality.  Perhaps there is a drinking culture among management, or alcohol is expensive and only rich people can afford to drink.

Comment: Questions like this ordinarily are addressed by regressing wage on drinking, controlling for age, and testing the drinking coefficient. The test statistic would be the estimated coefficient divided by its standard error.  If significantly different from zero, it would be interpreted as evidence only of an *association* (unless you have conducted an experiment in which you changed the drinking status of individuals and monitored how their wages changed subsequently!).

Comment: @Henry You are right, I'm trying to decide what would be the test statistic in this case in order to run a simulation and calculate the p-value. But without knowing the test statistic I cant proceed. Here it's not so straightforward like other cases. For example, it's easy to test the hypothesis that 50% of the population are drinkers, the test statistic would just be 700/1400 - half of the random sample population. But in my case, it's not that simple and I'm trying to get it right.

Comment: To test whether 50% of the population are drinkers, the test statistic would be the difference between the proportion *in the sample* and the hypothetical 50% value, all divided by the standard error of the sample proportion.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for explaining. So the answer to my question would be "The test statistic would be the estimated coefficient divided by its standard error"? If so, what do you mean by estimated coefficient ?

Comment: It sounds like you might find a quick review of regression methods helpful.  Research "ordinary least squares regression" for basic concepts and approaches.

Comment: ok, I'll check it out, thank you.

Comment: You ask "[A]mong people who are 40 years old or more, does drinking increase the wage?" You can determine whether wages increase for such people in your data, but you cannot settle whether drinking is the **cause** of higher wages.

Comment: @BruceET What would you say is the test statistic in this case? how do I calculate it?